# codeigniter ActiveRecord method convert to query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Is there any online converter which converts active record method into raw sql query? For example I have this method :

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('choices');
$this->db->where('quest_no', $quest_no);
$this->db->where('is_correct', '1');        
$query = $this->db->get();
```

and I want to convert it to

```
SELECT id FROM choices WHERE quest_no = $quest_no AND is_correct = 1
```

just for speed things up and quick understanding

Comment: After execution of your query you can also  use `$this->db->last_query();` to know the actual query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no website/application that convert the CodeIgniter Active record codes into raw query. You will need to used `last_query()` to get the last raw query you've executed. vice versa from raw sql to CodeIgniter Active record codes

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use codeigniter's `last_query()` function to see the standard query.

The function is used right after `get()` function as follows:

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('choices');
$this->db->where('quest_no', $quest_no);
$this->db->where('is_correct', '1');        
$query = $this->db->get();
echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;
```